# What do I need to escape inside the html <pre> tag

Tags: html, html-encode

I use the `<pre>` tag in my blog to post code. I know I have to change `<` to `&lt;` and `>` to `&gt;`. Are any other characters I need to escape for correct html?

Comment: By the way, what kind of blog is it? The underlying blog software may already translate some of the user input.

Comment: It's wordpress, but I always write straight into the plain text html.

Comment: Shoudln’t this depend on whether you want to generate proper HTML or XHTML (i.e. XML)?

Comment: You don't have to change `>` to `&gt;`. `>` is not seen as a tag-ender unless a tag is open, and if you change `<` to `&lt;` there's no way to open a tag, so `>` has no special meaning. But you need to chnage `&` to `&amp;` (and this needs to be done before other changes that include the ampersand).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What happens if you use the `<pre>` tag to display HTML markup on your blog:

```html
<pre>Use a <span style="background: yellow;">span tag with style attribute</span> to hightlight words</pre>
```

This will pass HTML validation, but does it produce the expected result? **No**. The correct way is:

```html
<pre>Use a &lt;span style=&quot;background: yellow;&quot;&gt;span tag with style attribute&lt;/span&gt; to hightlight words</pre>
```

Another example: if you use the pre tag to display some other language code, the HTML encoding is still required:

```
<pre>if (i && j) return;</pre>
```

This might produce the expected result but does it pass HTML validation? **No**. The correct way is:

```
<pre>if (i &amp;&amp; j) return;</pre>
```

Long story short, HTML-encode the content of a pre tag just the way you do with other tags.

Comment: "This might produce the expected result but does it pass HTML validation?" Yes. You only need to escape special characters in _HTML_.

Comment: The html this quote refers to uses `&&`

Comment: I just tried your code, `<pre>if (i && j) return;</pre>`, and it passed [validation](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input). Special characters in CSS and JavaScript code blocks don't need to be escaped.

Answer (score 11):

## TL;DR

- **PHP**: [`htmlspecialchars($html);`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)
- **JavaScript**(JS): [`Element.innerText = "<html>...";`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText)

Note that [`<pre>` is just for styles](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html), so you have to **escape ALL HTML**.

### Only For You HTML "fossil"s: using `<xmp>` tag

This is not well known, but it really does exist and even chrome still supports it, however using a **pair** of `<xmp>` tag is **NOT recommended** to be relied on - it's just for you HTML fossils, but it's a very simple way to handle your personal content, e.g. DOCS. Even the w3.org Wiki says in its example: "No, really. don't use it."

You can put ANY HTML (excluding `</xmp>` end tag) inside `<xmp></xmp>`

```
<xmp>
<html> <br> just any other html tags...
</xmp>
```

## The proper version

Proper version could be considered to be HTML stored as a **STRING** and displayed with the help of some **escaping** function/mechanism.

Just remember one thing - the strings in C-like languages are usually written between single quotes or double quotes - if you wrap your string in double => you should escape doubles (probably with `\`), if you wrap your string in single => escape singles (probably with `\`)...

### The most frequent - Server-side language escaping (ex. in PHP)

Server-side scripting languages often have some built-in function to escape HTML.

```
<?php
   $html = "<html> <br> or just any other HTML"; //store html
   echo htmlspecialchars($html); //display escaped html
?>
```

Note that in PHP **8.1** there was a change so you no longer have to specify `ENT_QUOTES` flag:

> flags changed from ENT_COMPAT to ENT_QUOTES | ENT_SUBSTITUTE | ENT_HTML401.

### The client-side way (example in JavaScript / JS&jQuery)

Similar approach as on server-side is achievable in client-side scripts.

#### Pure JavaScript

There is no function, but there is the default behavior, if you set [element's `innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) or [node's `textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent):

```
document.querySelector('.myTest').innerText = "<html><head>...";
document.querySelector('.myTest').textContent = "<html><head>...";
```

[`HTMLElement.innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) and [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) **are not the same thing!** You can find out more about the difference in the MDN doc links above

#### jQuery (a JS library)

jQuery has [`$jqueryEl.text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/#text2) for this purpose:

`$('.mySomething .test').text("<html><head></head><body class=\"test\">...");`

Just remember the same thing as for server-side - in C-like languages, escape the quotes you've wrapped your string in.

Answer (score -1):

For posting code within your markup, I suggest using the [<code>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535224(VS.85).aspx) tag.  It works the same way as pre but would be considered semantically correct.

Otherwise, <code> and <pre> only need the angle brackets encoded.

Comment: The original intent of pre was to grant space within the markup to preserve characters that otherwise wouldn't display (ie: tabs, line breaks, multiple spaces, etc) on a non-editable surface (you could do the same with textarea, but textarea can be edited).

Also, there were times in the old days that tabular data would be displayed using pre.

Answer (score -5):

Use this and don't worry about any of them.

```
<pre>
${fn:escapeXml('
  <!-- all your code -->
')};
</pre>
```

You'll need to have jQuery enabled for it to work.